# How far back does TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE history go?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've just discovered https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage-timeline which is described as

> The table storage views give you a convenient way to observe your current and historical storage consumption, including logical, compressed, and maintenance bytes. This information can help you with tasks like planning for future growth and understanding the update patterns for tables, even for tables that don't have a
> last_update timestamp column as part of the schema.

It is currently in preview

[image]

I ran this query:

```sql
select min(timestamp)
from `my-project.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE`
```

which returned:

> 2022-04-23 12:21:46.911787 UTC

which is exactly one month ago, in other words there is only one month's worth of history in here.

I consider this a limitation, I'd like to know about that history over a much later timeframe than that. Is this one-month limitation only during preview or will this always be the case?

Comment: I couldn't find an answer either, but April was already 3 months ago :) . Edit: actually the link in your question does mention "90 days" for some columns (e.g. search for "ACTIVE_LOGICAL_BYTES" on the page). Still not a definitive answer I guess, but the 3 months limit seems to be likely IMO.

Comment: Oh yeah. Good point 

Comment: Hi @jamiet , I have created an issue in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/240526642) for your issue where you can track the progress.

Answer (score 2):

`TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE` (along with `TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_ORGANIZATION`) were introduced in BigQuery Release Notes at April 25, 2022.
So I can speculate that this is the reason why you see data starting April 23 - so not because of 90 days limit

As of 90 days mentioned in documentation - this is about Long Term storage, so you know how much of your data is billed at regular price vs. at long term storage price

Comment: Looks like that is the case. The min timestamp hasnt changed since I wrote the post above. Good news.